# DataTable generating unwanted extra columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to pouplate datatable with data from the server but its generating non existent `td` which I have not defined.

Javascript

```
 $('.datatable-basic').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": base_url + 'leave/DraftJSON/'            
        },

         "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "sd" },
            { "data": "end" },
            { "data": "id"}       

        ] 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table datatable-basic" >
<thead>
  <tr>                                                                    
     <th>Leave</th>                                                              
     <th>Start</th>                                                               
     <th>End</th>                                                                 
     <th class="text-center" col="2">Actions</th>
   </tr>
</thead>                                                                                                                        
</table>
```

Ajax Request Response:

```
{"data":[{"id":"2","uid":"2","lid":"2","sd":"21 June, 2017","stod":"Afternoon","end":"21 June, 2017"
,"etod":"Afternoon","reason":"ddada","rid":"1","draft":"0","name":"Compassionate","person":"Ms. Ochieng
, Alphonc O"},{"id":"3","uid":"1","lid":"4","sd":"2017\/06\/20","stod":"Morning","end":"2017\/06\/22"
,"etod":"Afternoon","reason":"qeqeqeq","rid":"1","draft":"0","name":"Paternity","person":"Ms. Ochieng
, Alphonc O"}]}
```

HTML generated by DataTable:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="odd" role="row">
     <td class="sorting_1">Compassionate</td>
     <td>21 June, 2017</td>
     <td>21 June, 2017</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td></td> //non-existent
     <td></td> //non-existent
  </tr>
  <tr class="even" role="row">
     <td class="sorting_1">Paternity</td>
     <td>2017/06/20</td>
     <td>2017/06/22</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td></td> //non-existent
     <td></td> //non-existent
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The commented `td`s are extra sadded by datatable which then produces an error. Any insights?

Comment: You should equalize your th and column counts to solve the problem

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: I think the problem here is that datatables generates extra td's and OP doesn't want that.
@Alphy, any chance you're using IE? did you try this on another browser?

Comment: It is the same in all browsers, Chrome, IE and Mozilla. Not working as of yet

Comment: @user8175473 I only added more th to equalize as you suggested. But my main problem is why is it generating extra th

Comment: @Alphy I have updated my answer with plunker. It works here as you wish. https://plnkr.co/edit/ConoDQSvASevpZuh8X8M?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It works [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JRVin3fiajW02SVIJAMY?p=preview) as you wish.

When I tried to beautify your json file json formatter gived me an error in person property. I removed invalid character in person property and prepared plunker with your json data.

```
{
  "data":
  [
    {
      "id":"2",
      "uid":"2",
      "lid":"2",
      "sd":"21 June, 2017",
      "stod":"Afternoon",
      "end":"21 June, 2017",
      "etod":"Afternoon",
      "reason":"ddada",
      "rid":"1",
      "draft":"0",
      "name":"Compassionate",
      "person":"Ms. Ochieng, Alphonc O"
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "uid":"1",
      "lid":"4",
      "sd":"2017\/06\/20",
      "stod":"Morning",
      "end":"2017\/06\/22",
      "etod":"Afternoon",
      "reason":"qeqeqeq",
      "rid":"1",
      "draft":"0",
      "name":"Paternity",
      "person":"Ms. Ochieng, Alphonc O"
    }
  ]

}
```

**//jquery**

```
$('.datatable-basic').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'data.json'            
        },

         "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "sd" },
            { "data": "end" },
            { "data": "id"}       
        ] 
});
```